# Is the surface of a donut distinguishable from pac-man's world?

Tags: general-topology

Pac-man's world is topologically like the surface a donut. Pac-man's world is also locally flat. For example, the interior angles of a small triangle will always add up to 180 degrees.

Conversely, when I picture a donut in my mind, it's not very flat. Dissimilar to pac-man's world. Yet I'm having trouble coming up with a way to distinguish between the donut's surface and pac-man's world from the inside of the space.

(When I say 'donut' I mean a literal donut embedded in 3d space, with a hole through the middle and all that, but from the perspective of ants walking on the surface trying to figure out if they're pac-man or not.)

[image: Donut]

(Maybe the fact that the inside diameter is smaller than the outside diameter?)

Comment: Yes, a flat torus (the usual kind used in mathematics, and as found in Pac-man) has Gaussian curvature zero at every point.

Comment: What is your definition of locally flat? Because it seems obvious to me that the standard embedding of the torus in three dimensions is locally flat by the Wikipedia definition.

Comment: @GEdgar Right, but I'm interested in the surface of an actual donut embedded in 3d space with a hole through the middle and an ant walking along it.

Comment: But the inside diamater and outside diameter are not intrinsic measurements. 2d creatures living on the surface of the donut are unaware of measurements in 3d space.

Comment: From the outside looking in, the net curvature is 0, but parts of the surface are positively curved and parts are negatively curved.  From the inside, though, it may appear just as it does to pac-man.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your picture of the surface of a donut is correct: it is curved.

Not all metrics on a topological surface will have the same local properties.

For example, although a donut surface does indeed have flat metrics, it also has nonflat metrics, and the donut surface is one of them. 2d entities living on the surface of a donut could indeed distinguish their donut from pac-man's world, by making little measurements of length and area. For instance, they could measure the radius and area of a small circle on their world, and for almost any circle they chose, they would discover that the formula $A=\pi r^2$ fails, so their world is not flat.

More specifically, if they take a small circle centered at a point on the inside of the torus, $A > \pi r^2$ (the surface is negatively curved in the inside region). On the other hand, if they take a small circle centered at a point on the outside of the torus, $A < \pi r^2$ (the surface is positively curved in the outside region).

Comment: Ah, I see it now. A point on the inner circle (the one around the hole) is like a saddle, but the points on the outside circle are like a cap. And those can be detected locally.

Answer (score -1):

The portal thing where Pac-man goes to the mid-left side of the screen and appears on the mid-right side of the screen would also be explained by a donut world.

Comment: This would actually be a grand answer in my opinion, if you'd elaborate a bit.